# share capital, shares

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am translating the Articles of Association of a Russian limited company into English.
The company is owned by three persons. Each of them has a 33-34% stake in the business.
They do not have any shares. The company does not issue any shares.
Each of the company  owners has contributed a nominal amount at the time of the business registration.
These nominal amounts form a certain capital.
What would you call such a capital? 
First, I used “share capital” to refer to it but then I read some article in the Internet that a company that does not issue shares cannot have a share capital.
Now I think that maybe I should call it "membership interest capital", but I am not sure. 
Also what would be the best term to refer to the percentage of a business owned by each of the holders? Can I call it share in the business or should I rather use “stake”, “equity stake” or “membership interest”? 
Thank you very much for your time and answers.

Comment: Though an accountant most of my life, I am no expert in company law, certainly not the Russian variety. But in British jargon we do talk about "nominal capital" - e.g. *the company has a small nominal capital, divided into XYZ shares, but a large amount of loan capital and accumulated earnings*. Certainly if a company does not issue shares it could not, by definition, have a "share capital". In the UK it would probably be regarded as a partnership.

Comment: I like the expression but most dictionaries define it as the par value of shares of stock a corporation has issued or as an alternative term for authorized share capital.

Comment: [This website](http://www.companylawclub.co.uk/authorised-capital) seems to have an understanding of UK Company Law, and they do use the term "nominal capital" as an alternative to "authorised capital" (the requirement for which was abolished in 2009) - see the paragraph "under the Companies Act 1985". But none of this is clearly of any help to you so far as Russia is concerned! If the shareholders have actually subscribed certain amounts, I suppose you could call it "paid-up capital".

Answer (score 1):

You’re welcome to think I’m picking nits here and can we first be really clear that WS2’s link gives a fine example of both how detailed and how utterly pointless is most of British company law?

*… any company… will have no restriction on the number of shares it can issue, unless a limit is set in the company's articles*. In what way is that helpful?

*… a company's authorised or nominal capital… was the maximum… share capital the company could issue (unless it went through a procedure to increase the figure)* Just how would that *procedure* stop you doing whatever?

*… authorised capital had to be stated as a sum of money divided into shares…* e.g. *… £50,000 divided into 50,000 shares of £1 each.* Really? What does primary-school arithmetic contribute in either legal or accounting terms?

From Russia or any other country, I suggest you are not talking about a limited company, but some other kind of business; possibly a partnership. Either way, shares will be relevant.

To turn this round… lawyers and accountants, jump in and shoot me down… the working definition of a limited company is an organisation whose legal *liability* is limited to the amount of its paid-up share capital, which is the amount the founder members are supposed to have paid for their shares; specifically and solely, what they paid for their shares

Going way further than the scope of the question an ordinary person such as you and I can be sued for everything we have, and so can a limited company… but what you or I have might be debatable; what a company has is clearly limited by exactly how much the shareholders paid in and what has been spent or sold since, to the penny.

Crucially, you or I will be bankrupt only when the bank manager loses confidence and cuts off the overdraft; a limited company will be bankrupt immediately any creditor is not satisfied where any debt is coming from, to the penny.

Because of these basic axioms it is generally not stated in writing that a company exists only through shares and shareholders, who and which are not at all the same as partners or investors, lenders or other creditors.

To the extent that Russian company law is different, the very concepts might not be capable of translation… which can’t really mean the task is impossible and so must mean you need some specially qualified collaborators.

Going back to what we do know, if the company is owned by three persons then how, exactly, are their stakes defined? The answer cannot be that each has a 33-34% stake because by shares or any other measure, that will never be precise. Of course my 10-11% stake is always going to be less than your 33-34% and that's very different. Neither a British nor a Russian court will accept the ambiguity in *33-34%*.

Go back to how the company’s liability is limited to the amount of its paid-up share capital and please recognise that the term *nominal* is there used to rule out any questions. The *nominal* value is what I’m *supposed to have* paid for my shares.

British company law doesn’t allow; scarcely even recognises the idea of a shareholder owing anything against the value of shares which is why the only thing that matters is the *nominal* value… which is almost the opposite of the idea that a share *nominally* worth £1 has a real market value of what? 10p or £10,000… it matters not.

That what anyone contributed at the time of the business registration might matter is another indicator that this is not about what British law sees as a limited company. In British law a limited company must have at least one share at the time of registration; for practical purposes, at least three. That is wholly irrelevant from any perspective, against the *total* number of shares *ever* issued.

You’re quite right; a company which does not issue shares cannot have a share capital. Again, *nominal* capital refers to cash which either the investor has already paid it in, or can be demanded without notice. Anything else would invalidate the shareholding and immediately make a company insolvent; bankrupt.

The *nominal* contributions do form a certain capital, and that is described in legal or accounting terms simply as *capital*.

Calling it *share capital* or *membership interest capital* or any other special term merely confuses the issue. that goes right back to exactly what difference  you see, or you think a court might see, among *membership interest capital* or *membership capital*  or *interest capital* or any other kind of capital.

After all that how could it matter what anyone calls the percentage of a business owned by each of the owners?

Calling it *a share in the business* is only arithmetically equivalent to calling the owners *shareholders* or *stake-holders* or *partners* or *principals* or anything else. That Tommy Atkins has a 30% share in a business doesn’t make that business a company and it doesn’t make Mr Atkins a shareholder in the usual sense of the word.

Broadly, you need specially qualified collaborators.

Comment: What about private companies limited by guarantee? They also do not have any shares and their liability is still limited. Their members contribute nominal amounts to the company capital. I've looked through several Articles of Associations of these companies. They either avoid using the word "capital" (which is not an option for me) or call it simply "the capital". The latter, I'm afraid, may confuse the issue as well. Someone might think it includes other kinds of assets.

Comment: I've asked the same question on several legal forums and nobody could help me so far :(. Russian translators' community are not helpful as well. Everyone uses whichever he/she likes more with no actually good reason. I've seen "share capital", "authorised capital", "registered capital", "stated capital", "charter capital" etc. None of them describes the concept.

Comment: Sadly the law today is broadly the same which allowed the Honourable East India Company to 'own' the sub continent and the Hudson's Bay Company to 'own' half of North America; equivalent to Spain, Portugal and the Pope ‘giving’ the Conquistadors South America.

How does that nonsense translate to Russian, please?

Lacking a fluent linguist with legal knowledge or a fluent lawyer with linguistic knowledge, my suggestion would be to look not at theory but at real Russian case law.

Alternatively join your local Chamber of Commerce and ask members for help.

Comment: Two more pieces of nonsense I forgot to mention…

*Shares* in fact have no more real existence than *companies* which is why British law requires the *issuing of share certificates* to be registered. The *certifcates* have a real physical existence; the *shares* are a legal fiction.

Cut a cake into shares, issue ration coupons and there are three, not two elements even though cut, the cake has become purely conceptual. Companies have the concept of their existence and the fact of their share certificates; now, the shares themselves are purely conceptual.

Comment: Members don’t invest in companies limited by guarantee. They give guarantees as collateral, and might lend their own cash.

Guarantees can be called in to deal with problems. Normally, how will members be apportioned dividends? Uh… according to their share of investments and guarantees, even though no *shares* exist, even in theory.

Further complications arise with *partners* who if *equal* share rewards and liabilities; unequal partners have different *shares*… 

Simples! The real differences are in taxes and disclosure to regulators - including Theresa May’s *Fat Cats* campaign.